# MLA citations in LyX

Tags: lyx, mla-style

I tried several times to get MLA citations working, but I always hit some wall (mostly the problem is that LyX doesn't build in project directory - only files that it's aware of are being copied to a temporary build directory).

### My question

How can one get working MLA citations in LyX with functional citation tools of LyX (I mean working `Insert -> Citation...` and `Insert -> List/TOC -> BibTeX bibliography`).

---

Please, do not post general LaTeX/TeX answers - I found several of them, but I was unable to make it working in LyX.